# Jquery Select DIV below Table

Tags: jquery

I have some simple markup:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Menu Item</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Menu Item Sub Menu</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Im currently hiding the DIV, however if you click the  in the first table I want it to .show() the Table in the div.

Does that make sense?

I should really get my head around, parent(), next(), find()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to add an `id` to the `div` and `table`, you can do the following. I use `toggle()` instead of `show()`, but replace with `show()` if you want.

```
$("table").click(function(){
   $("div").toggle();
   return false;
});
```

But, i'd add an `id` to the `table` and `div`, then a click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1").hide();
   $("#table1").click(function(){
      $("#div1").toggle();
      return false;
   });
});
```

Or if you want to use `next()`, try this for the click function:

```
$("#table1").click(function(){
   $(this).next().toggle();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: packed jquery not advised anymore. min + gzip = best performance

Comment: @redsquare - Thanks. Just copy-pasted the script lines over from an old test. Either way, edited that out.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive reply!

Answer (score 2):

Give the first table an id

```
$('#theTable').next().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(table).siblings('div');
```

Gives you all [siblings](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings) to the element table that are a div. You should make sure that there is only this div (or another way that you can uniquely select it).